# Relay activation

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, programming

I am posting my simple code here, I wanted to print the Output_Current Inspite when delay function called.Below is my code.

```
#include <MsTimer2.h>


int Analog_Pin=5;
int newaverage;
float Output_Current;
#define RELAY1  7
#define MAX_TRIP_COUNT  5
float Current_Limit=0.6;
static int Trip_Count=0;
static int Tripped_Flag=1;
int Serial_Status=0;



void TakeReading()
{
  newaverage = analogRead(A5);

//  Serial.print("newaverage:");
  //Serial.println(newaverage);
  Output_Current = 0.0336666666667*newaverage - 17.17; 
}


void Chk_Relay_Tripped()
{
  if(Output_Current>=Current_Limit)
  {
    Trip_Count=Trip_Count+1; 
    if((Trip_Count>=MAX_TRIP_COUNT) &&(Serial_Status==0))
    {

      Trip_Count=0;

  MsTimer2::set(30000, Relay_Activate); // 500ms period
  MsTimer2::start();
     // Relay_Activate();
    }
    else
      if(Serial_Status==1)
      {
        Serial.println("> MODE");
        Relay_Deactivate(); 
      }

  } 
  else
  {
    Trip_Count=Trip_Count-1;
    if(Trip_Count<0)
    {
      Trip_Count=0;
    }

    if(Trip_Count<MAX_TRIP_COUNT && Serial_Status==1)
    {
      Relay_Deactivate();
      Serial_Status=0;
    }

  }

}




void Relay_Activate()
{
   // MsTimer2::stop();

   for (unsigned long start = millis(); millis() - start < 10000;)
  {
    digitalWrite(RELAY1,HIGH);
    Serial_Status=1;
  }

    digitalWrite(RELAY1,HIGH);
    Serial_Status=1;

}

void  Relay_Deactivate()
{
  digitalWrite(RELAY1,LOW);
 // Serial_Status=0;
}

void Relay_Intialize()
{
  digitalWrite(RELAY1,LOW);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // set serial speed
  pinMode(RELAY1, OUTPUT); // set LED as output
  //digitalWrite(RELAY1, LOW); //turn off LED

  pinMode(Analog_Pin,INPUT);
  Relay_Intialize();
}




void loop(){
  TakeReading();
  Chk_Relay_Tripped();
  Serial.println(Output_Current);
   //while (Serial.available() == 0); // do nothing if nothing sent
  int val = Serial.read() - '0';
  if (val == 1) { // test for command 1 then turn on LED
    Serial.println("RELAY on");
    digitalWrite(RELAY1, LOW); // turn on LED
    Serial_Status=1;

  }
  else if (val == 0) // test for command 0 then turn off LED
  {
    Serial.println("RELAY OFF");
    digitalWrite(RELAY1, HIGH); // turn off LED
    Serial_Status=0;
  }
  delay(500);
}
```

In above code everything working fine. But as soon as this function called . It wait 30s. after that it will print data. But i wanted to print data on serial monitor even if this function called. Please let me know how can i do this. Main intenstion of code is when current >1A trip the relay , wait for 30S and connect back. I wanted to print output even in 30S

```
void Relay_Activate()
{

   for (unsigned long start = millis(); millis() - start < 30000;)
  {
    digitalWrite(RELAY1,HIGH);
    Serial_Status=1;
  }

}
```

Comment: I totally don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Reading the code doesn't make it any clearer. A better description would be helpful.

Comment: @Gerben this code clarify it. I wanted to print all data within 30S delay

Answer (score 0):

I read you code as: check the output current every 500ms. If it exceeds the limit more than `MAX_TRIP_COUNT` times, set `Relay_Activate` to run after 30secs. In `Relay_Activate`, write `HIGH` to the `RELAY1` over and over for 30 seconds:

```
void Relay_Activate()
{
  for (unsigned long start = millis(); millis() - start < 30000;)
  {
    digitalWrite(RELAY1,HIGH);
    Serial_Status=1;
  }
}
```

I don't think you really mean to do this, especially as after the 30 seconds you are not writing `LOW` to turn it off. Maybe you mean that after 30 seconds it should start checking the current again?

```
void Relay_Activate()
{
  digitalWrite(RELAY1,HIGH);
  Serial_Status=1;
}
```

What you want is a state machine so that your delays don't hold up your loop. Here is some pseudo code:

```
loop {

* read current
* print out current

switch(current_state) {
  //Normal operation
  case 0:
    * check if tripped
      - if tripped change state to 1
  //Turn on relay
  case 1:
    * turn on relay
    * set state_timer = millis()
    * change state to 2
  //Turn of relay after 30 seconds
  case 2:
    * if millis() -state_timer > 30000 turn off relay
    * change state to 0
}
delay 500ms
}
```

Comment: So post your updated code along with an explanation of what you did, and accept it as the answer to your question. That way your question becomes a way for others to learn.